# VB6 application failed to run in another computer

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, windows-8.1, visual-basic

I have created an application on my computer (Windows 7) using Visual basic 6 and it works well.

Now when I copied the application to another computer running Windows 8.1, the application was unable to run, prompting error "unable to create link".

In the application I created, I've used OLE control to link an Excel file and a short WAV file to the application, thus I copied the files to exactly same directory address on both computer, but the error is still there. Anyone may help on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: After I removed the OLE Control module from my codes, I managed to run the program smoothly. Is this means that I have made any mistake or not done something to the OLE Control module that link an Excel file to my program?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the application in compatibility mode?

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27861556/2505109) you are going to start running into this issue more and more often. It might be time to consider moving your application to the [.NET framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903378%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: I've tried that but it just keep showing Run-time error "31024" (Unable to create link). 

I'm considering to move my application to .NET framework in the future but I never learn .NET programming before and this program is quite urgent to run on the new PC.

Comment: This [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243097%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) suggests the spreadsheet is too large. How big is it?